# Не могу понять код

Tags: c#

Страница 50 книги "C# для начинающих" Мартина Дрейера. В код необходимо добавить метод.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyButtonClass : Form
{
private Button mrButton;

public MyButtonClass ()
    {

        this.Text = "форма с работающей кнопкой";
        mrButton = new Button();
        mrButton.Text = "нажми меня";
        mrButton.Top = 100;
        mrButton.Left = 100;
        mrButton.Height = 50;
        mrButton.Width = 100;

        this.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(TheMouseIsDown);

        mrButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(azaza);
        this.Controls.Add(mrButton);
}
static void Main()
{
    Application.Run(new MyButtonClass());
}
// метод обработчик событий

void azaza(object x, EventArgs y)
{
    mrButton.Text = "вы нажали меня!";
}   

public void TheMouseIsDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button = MouseButtons.Left)
        this.Text = "нажата левая кнопка мыши";
 }
}
```

В книге указано написать так  `if (e.Button = MouseButtons.Left)` для метода, но один знак "равно" это же вроде не верно, и в данном случае visual studio выдает ошибку "невозможно присвоить значение свойству или индексатору, доступ только для чтения". А если поставить два знака "равно" то ошибки нет, но потом возникает вопрос куда вообще должен выводится текст с сообщением "нажата левая кнопка мыши", должно поменяться название самой формы или нет?

Comment: В данном случае текст должен показываться вместо старого `"форма с работающей кнопкой"`. Т.к. вы заменяете именно этот текст таким действием. 
С условием Вы правильно заметили. Там должно быть `==`.

Comment: в методе `TheMouseIsDown` должна происходить проверка, что пользователь нажал левую кнопку мыши, поэтому должено быть `e.Button == MouseButtons.Left`. А текст должен выводится туда же куда выводится `this.Text = "форма с работающей кнопкой";
`

Comment: Странно но название формы все равно не меняется, в чем может быть еще проблема кроме моих кривых рук? @Bulson

Comment: @ВладимирПересвет средством от кривых рук программиста является дебагинг или пошаговое выполнение нужного участка программы. Навык дебагинга так же необходим как собственно умение писать и читать код. Поставьте точку останова на открывающую скобку у метода `TheMouseIsDown()` и далее пройдите вперед просматривая значения локальных переменных.

Comment: Найдите в той книге, которую вы читаете раздел про дебагинг и трассировку программ и ознакомитесь с тем как это делается.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. Оказалось что только при нажатии на пустом месте срабатывает метод и название формы меняется.@Bulson